# How to access the state of apollo (GraphQL) query triggered by click event

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, apollo, vue-apollo

In vue application I need to run gql query when user clicks the button. So the HTML part has the button:

```
<div 
  :id="'button-' + id"
  class="more-button" 
  @click="showDetails(id)">&nbsp;</div>
```

And the corresponding function is doing some debug `console.log` and firing the `this.apollo.query`. 
The problem is that I can see in the console all console.log output, so the function executes, but none of the hooks: error/result/watchLoading happens. **At least I do not see anything in the console output.**

```
showDetails(item) {
  console.log("before: " + msid);
  let msid = this.position.instrument.morningstarId;
  this.xxx = msid;
  this.$apollo.query({
    query: GET_INSTRUMENT,
    variables: {
      morningstarId: this.position.instrument.morningstarId
    },
    result({ data }) {
      console.log("L data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error(error) {
      alert("L We've got an error!" + JSON.stringify(error));
    },
    watchLoading(isLoading) {
      console.log("L isLoading: " + isLoading);
    }
  });
  console.log("after: " + msid);
}
```

When I move all the content of `this.$apollo.query` to `apollo` section in the component, all works OK. So the working code after the change looks like this:

```
...
data() {
  return {
    instrument: null
  };
},
  apollo: {
    instrument: {
      query: GET_INSTRUMENT,
      variables() {
        return {
          morningstarId: this.position.instrument.morningstarId
        };
      },
      result({ data }) {
        console.log("G data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
      },
      error(error) {
        alert("G We've got an error!" + JSON.stringify(error));
      },
      watchLoading(isLoading) {
        console.log("G isLoading: " + isLoading);
      }
    }
  },
computed
...
```

But I do not want to have this query called when the component is built. I want to have it called only from the function. I am not interested in using the `skip()` method as a solution like described [here](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo/issues/121).

The question is: what am I doing wrong, that any of the watchLoading/error/result hooks logs anything to the console?

There is neither error, nor warning in the console. But if force error in example by changing:

```
  this.$apollo.query({
    query: GET_INSTRUMENT,
```

to

```
  this.$apollo.query({
    q_uery: GET_INSTRUMENT,
```

then I see in the console:

*QueryManager.js?96af:473 Uncaught Error: query option is required. You must specify your GraphQL document in the query option.*

So I am sure that apollo is working with the query. But i have no idea how to access the result or state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to treat the `query` like Promise and use `then` method on it.

As described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise): *The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value*.

So instead of the code I was using:

```
showDetails(item) {
  console.log("before: " + msid);
  let msid = this.position.instrument.morningstarId;
  this.xxx = msid;
  this.$apollo.query({
    query: GET_INSTRUMENT,
    variables: {
      morningstarId: this.position.instrument.morningstarId
    },
    result({ data }) {
      console.log("L data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error(error) {
      alert("L We've got an error!" + JSON.stringify(error));
    },
    watchLoading(isLoading) {
      console.log("L isLoading: " + isLoading);
    }
  });
  console.log("after: " + msid);
}
```

**The working code to access the results and handle the error is**:

```
showDetails(item) {
    this.$apollo
      .query({
        query: GET_INSTRUMENT,
        variables: {
          morningstarId: this.instrumentObj.instrument.morningstarId,
          freq: this.chartFrequency
        }
      })
      .then(data => {
        this.instrument = data.data.instrument;
        this.loading = data.loading;
        this.networkStatus = data.networkStatus;
        this.generatePastChart();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
        alert("E " + error);
      });

}
```

`then` method registers a callback function with retrieved data object as an input parameter.
`catch` handles the failure

Comment: How to fetch updated data from server this way? It's only once retrieves data from server.